# Google mock: Mocking parent class?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, testing, mocking, googlemock

Assume I have a base class:

```
class Command {
public:
    virtual int8_t Execute();
};
```

with a definition in the base class cpp.

Additionally, I have a child class:

```
class SpecificCommand: public Command {
public:
    int8_t Execute();
};
```

With the definition:

```
int8_t SpecificCommand::Execute() {
    doSomeStuff();
    Command::Execute();
}
```

How do I mock Command::Execute() but using a SpecificCommand object for tests?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like that:

```
class SpecificCommandMock : public SpecificCommand
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD0(ExecuteMockedMethod, void());
    int8_t Execute() override
    {
        doSomeStuff()
        ExecuteMockedMethod();
    }
}
```

Of course you should use `SpecificCommandMock` in unit tests and set `EXPECT_CALL` for `ExecuteMockedMethod` when class under test is expected to call `Execute()`.

In addition I suppose that something could be wrong in design of the application if you have to do such things.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you clarify what in your opinion could be wrong with the actual production code design?

Comment: As a general rule each separate public method should be normally testable so why do you need to mock only `Command::Execute()?` Are you sure that using e.g. `EXPECT_CALL(...).WillRepeatedly(Return(something))` isn't good solution in you case?

Comment: Command::Execute() consists of network access that can not be tested with googletest yet as the test is not executed on the target system. So I want to mock (or is it fake in this case?) it. Execute does modify some member variables declared in Command. Do you know a better way of doing so?

Comment: I would consider extracting part which is responsible for network connection to the separate class. Next I can pass reference (or pointer) to the instance of this class in `SpecificCommandMock` constructor. In production code it will be a reference to the class which really connects to the network, but in unit tests it will be only mock.

Answer (score 0):

This should not be possible in the way you are expecting. I.e. gtest cannot just replace the part of your code and instead of:

```
int8_t SpecificCommand::Execute() {
    doSomeStuff();
    Command::Execute();
}
```

execute something like:

```
int8_t SpecificCommand::Execute() {
    doSomeStuff();
}
```

You operate with macroses mainly which are just wrap your code with some other. So the language limitation still in there.

Some options (which don't affect your Command implementation):

- if `doSomeStuff` is a public -  override the `Execute()` with mock class as proposed by [trivelt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3424163/trivelt) or do it like official [docs](http://google.github.io/googletest/gmock_cook_book.html#delegating-calls-to-a-real-object) suggests with ON_CALL declaration in mock constructor
- write `DummyCommand.cpp` which do nothing and by compilation option build it instead of original one. In `cmake` it's `if-else` + `add_library/add_executable` manipulations.
- write mock to the library which uses "network access that can not be tested" and link it instead of original one by compilation option. (`if-else` + `target_link_library` or even `include` manipulations in the cmake)
- write mock for the network communication backend (web_server, etc)